# What are succ and pred full names?

Tags: ocaml, naming

I fount the following in Inria documentation for [Pervasives](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html):

> val succ : int -> int
>
> succ x is x + 1.
>
> val pred : int -> int
>
> pred x is x - 1.

As I understand **succ** and **pred** are short names. What are their full names?

Comment: They're respectively the abbreviations of *successor* and  *predecessor* ?

Comment: yes, it's looks like absolutely true. Can your write you comment as answer for give me possibility for close this question?

Comment: You can delete your question, can you not? (At least *before* anyone writes an answer.)

Comment: Yes this question is easy, but I had no answer before. I think this post will be good contribution to stackoverflow knowledge and can help somebody in future.

Comment: It's rather a borderline case, that's why - as I still wanted to help you - I did not formulate it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are respectively the abbreviations of successor and predecessor.